# boxes around figures in tikz matrix aligned environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have 4 figures (written in tikz), which I aligned in 2x2 matrix format using \matrix from tikz. Now I want to draw box around each figure and add captions to each figure below its respective box. The format for my tex code is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[draw]
{
   <figure-1 details>;
   &
   <figure-2 details>;
   \\
   <figure-3 details>;
   &
   <figure-4 details>;
   \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

Figure-1 tikz code

```
        \coordinate(v3) at (-2.5,0);
        \node[left] at (v3) {$v_3$};
        \coordinate(v2) at (0,4.3301); 
        \node[above] at (v2) {$v_2$};
        \coordinate(v4) at (2.5,0); 
        \node[right] at (v4) {$v_4$};
        \draw[thick] (v2)--(v3)--(v4)--cycle;
        \coordinate(v5) at (0,0);
        \node[below] at (v5) {$v_5$};
        \draw[thin] (v2)--(v5);
        \coordinate(v6) at (-1.25,2.165);
        \node[left] at (v6) {$v_6$};
        \draw[thin] (v5)--(v6);
        \coordinate(v7) at (1.25,2.165);
        \node[right] at (v7) {$v_7$};
        \draw[thin] (v5)--(v7);
        \fill[black] (0,1.4433) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {$c_1$};
        \fill[black] (-0.833,1.443) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {$c_2$};
        \fill[black] (0.833,1.443) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {$c_3$};
        \fill[very nearly transparent] (v2)--(v4)--(v5)--cycle;
```

---

Other figures are similar to figure-1 except for minor changes in shading regions i.e. some other inner triangle being filled.

Comment: Can you make a complete example? Doesn't have to be the complete diagrams, but at least something similar, so that it's clear how you constructed them. That said, sounds like you'd be better off by not using a single `tikzpicture` with a `\matrix`, but instead use e.g. four `subfigure` environments from the `subcaption` package, and have a separate `tikzpicture` in each.

Comment: Why do you use `matrix` to align figures? A `tabular`could be enough.

Comment: @Ignasi: I never knew that tabular can be used with tikz figures. I will take a look into this one.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes I finally did it with subfig but it was not that satisfactory. All I need is bounding box, \matrix automatically aligns the figures.

Comment: You said you needed a caption, is that not the case?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to write that in a hurry. My mistake. Captions are needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could to, is to add something like the following at the end of each cell:

```
% draws a rectangle around the content of the cell, with some padding
\node [fit=(current bounding box),draw] (a) {};
% add caption below frame
\path
    let \p1=(a.west),\p2=(a.east),\n1={\x2-\x1} in
  node [below,text width=\n1] at (a.south) {%
     \captionof{subfigure}{This is a figure showing etc.}
  };
```

This is assuming that you want a numbered subcaption below each panel. If you don't want any numbered caption at all, remove `\captionof{subfigure}{` and the closing `}`.

If you want the caption *inside* the frame, swap the order of the `\node` and the `\path`, and place the caption node at `current bounding box.south` instead of `a.south`.

Note in the code below that I also suggested a different way of drawing your diagram, in the second cell.

That the horizontal alignment is different in the two columns seem to be caused by different coordinates used for the triangles. In your code the lower left corner is at `(-2.5,0)`, while in my code it is at `(0,0)`. Both the crosses in the second row has the left side at x=0. Note that x=0 in the first row aligns with x=0 in the second row.

In other words, as long as you use the same coordinates for all the triangles, the alignment should be correct.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption} % <-- added
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc} % <- added
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt} % <-- added
]
\matrix%[draw]
{
        \coordinate(v3) at (-2.5,0);
        \node[left] at (v3) {$v_3$};
        \coordinate(v2) at (0,4.3301); 
        \node[above] at (v2) {$v_2$};
        \coordinate(v4) at (2.5,0); 
        \node[right] at (v4) {$v_4$};
        \draw[thick] (v2)--(v3)--(v4)--cycle;
        \coordinate(v5) at (0,0);
        \node[below] at (v5) {$v_5$};
        \draw[thin] (v2)--(v5);
        \coordinate(v6) at (-1.25,2.165);
        \node[left] at (v6) {$v_6$};
        \draw[thin] (v5)--(v6);
        \coordinate(v7) at (1.25,2.165);
        \node[right] at (v7) {$v_7$};
        \draw[thin] (v5)--(v7);
        \fill[black] (0,1.4433) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {$c_1$};
        \fill[black] (-0.833,1.443) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {$c_2$};
        \fill[black] (0.833,1.443) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {$c_3$};
        \fill[very nearly transparent] (v2)--(v4)--(v5)--cycle;

        \node [fit=(current bounding box),draw] (a) {};
        \path
        let \p1=(a.west),\p2=(a.east),\n1={\x2-\x1} in
        node [below,text width=\n1] at (a.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{This is a figure showing etc.}};

   &

   \draw [thick] (0,0) coordinate[label=left:$v_3$] (v3)
            -- coordinate[label=below:$v_5$] (v5)
       ++(0:5) coordinate[label=right:$v_4$] (v4)
            -- coordinate[label=right:$v_7$] (v7)
     ++(120:5) coordinate[label=above:$v_2$] (v2)
            -- coordinate[label=left:$v_6$] (v6)
        cycle;
   \draw (v6) -- node[dot,pos=0.3,label=below:$c_2$] (c2) {} (v5)
              -- node[dot,pos=0.7,label=below:$c_3$] (c3) {} (v7);
   \node[dot,label=right:$c_1$] at (c2 -| v5) {};
   \draw (v2) -- (v5);
   \fill[very nearly transparent] (v2)--(v4)--(v5)--cycle;

        \node [fit=(current bounding box),draw] (b) {};
        \path
        let \p1=(b.west),\p2=(b.east),\n1={\x2-\x1} in
        node [below,text width=\n1] at (b.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{This is also a figure showing etc.}};

   \\

 \draw (0,0) -- (3,3) (0,3) -- (3,0);

        \node [fit=(current bounding box),draw] (b) {};
        \path
        let \p1=(b.west),\p2=(b.east),\n1={\x2-\x1} in
        node [below,text width=\n1] at (b.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{This is something else.}};


   &


 \draw (0,0) -- (3,3) (0,3) -- (3,0);

        \node [fit=(current bounding box),draw] (b) {};
        \path
        let \p1=(b.west),\p2=(b.east),\n1={\x2-\x1} in
        node [below,text width=\n1] at (b.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{This is something else.}};

   \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption for the whole thing}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively use a `tabular` with a `tikzpicture` in each cell, e.g.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption} % <-- added
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc} % <- added


\newcommand\diagram{% this macro is just to make the example easier to construct, see below
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt}
]
   \draw [thick] (0,0) coordinate[label=left:$v_3$] (v3)
            -- coordinate[label=below:$v_5$] (v5)
       ++(0:5) coordinate[label=right:$v_4$] (v4)
            -- coordinate[label=right:$v_7$] (v7)
     ++(120:5) coordinate[label=above:$v_2$] (v2)
            -- coordinate[label=left:$v_6$] (v6)
        cycle;
   \draw (v6) -- node[dot,pos=0.3,label=below:$c_2$] (c2) {} (v5)
              -- node[dot,pos=0.7,label=below:$c_3$] (c3) {} (v7);
   \node[dot,label=right:$c_1$] at (c2 -| v5) {};
   \draw (v2) -- (v5);
   \fill[very nearly transparent] (v2)--(v4)--(v5)--cycle;

        \node [fit=(current bounding box),draw,minimum size=6cm] (b) {};
        \path
        let \p1=(b.west),\p2=(b.east),\n1={\x2-\x1} in
        node [below,text width=\n1] at (b.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{This is also a figure showing etc.}};
\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
% I used a macro just for convenience, in your case put in the four
% different tikzpicture environments instead of \diagram
\diagram & \diagram \\
\diagram & \diagram 
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption for the whole thing}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have all four bounding boxes of same size,  and the 2nd row figures automatically adjusting themselves to center of their bounding box.

Comment: @user402940 You can set something like `minimum size=6cm` for all the `fit` nodes, but if they are of the same size, that won't be needed. For the alignment, seems that the x-coordinates in each cell of a column will be  aligned, and similarly each y-coordinate in a row.  So if all your triangles use the same coordinates, the alignment should be correct.

Comment: @user402940 Alternative; `tabular`, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Way easier with tabular thing rather than messing around with matrix or subfig.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing you code it is hard to say what the best way to do this is but given that you already have your code inside a [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) `\matrix` the easiest way is probably just to add `matrix of nodes` to your `\matrix` and add some styling to put a rectangle around each node. You can add the captions either by hand, or make them part of the matrix by adding some styling. The former is easier, so I've done it that way.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes, every node/.style={rectangle, draw},
          row sep=6mm, column sep=4mm,]
    {
       figure-1 details
       &
       figure-2 details
       \\
       figure-3 details
       &
       figure-4 details
       \\
    };
    \node at ([yshift=-6]M-1-1.south){\small Caption 1};
    \node at ([yshift=-6]M-1-2.south){\small Caption 2};
    \node at ([yshift=-6]M-2-1.south){\small Caption 3};
    \node at ([yshift=-6]M-2-2.south){\small Caption 4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `(M)` after `\matrix` means that the nodes have labels `(M-1-1)`, `(M-1-2)` etc. in the non-empty cells (with the option `nodes in empty cells` you can have nodes in the empty cells too). You can change `(M)` to anything you like.